# Nullpointer Exception Cannot invoke / java lang Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, mysqlconnector, mysqlprocedure

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta de mi Jframe en Netbeans 13. Estoy pasando un parámetro qué es el 1 es el ID, para que llene unas cajas de texto en el formulario. Bien, pero manda el siguiente error cuando ejecuto la consulta con un procedimiento almacenado:

"Error java lang Nullpointer Exception Cannot invoke "java sql prepared statement setint(int, int)" because "com.mycompany.proyecto.CConexion.pp" is null"

Entiendo, que no puedo mandar un null a la consulta, pero, de la interfaz / formulario si pasa el 1, ¿Qué problema podría ser?, algunos dicen que es el driver, pero, si fuese el driver no estaría conectando a la BD (MySQL). El código de la clase es el siguiente:

```
public static Resultset ListadeEnfermedadesxID (int Id_enfermedades){
      
try{
     conectar= DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, usuario, clave);  
      SP = conectar.prepareCall("{CALL SP_VerenfermedadesX_ID(?)}");
      pp.setInt(1, Id_enfermedades);            
      ResultSet rs = SP.executeQuery();         
      return (Resultset) rs;
  }
   catch(SQLException e){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ejecutó el Procedmiento almacenado SP_VerenfermedadesX_ID. Error"+ e.toString());
   }        
     return (Resultset) rs;
}
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?. Saludos y gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que llama al Procedimiento almacenado en MySQL al darle click en el Jtable / Grid:

```
public void ConsultarXID(){
           try{
               
              ResultSet rs = null;
              
              String Ids = this.txtIdEnfermedad.getText();
              int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids); 
               
              
              if (id >0){
               rs = (ResultSet) CConexion.ListadeEnfermedadesxID(
               Integer.parseInt(this.txtIdEnfermedad.getText())); //Llama los datos de MySQL con la clase
                          
             
                   while (rs.next()) // Recorre el ResultSet para llenar el modelo
                   {
                     
                      this.txtNomEnf.setText(rs.getString("Nombre_enf"));
                      this.txtDescripEnf.setText(rs.getString("Descrip"));
                      
                   }
                   this.lblIdEnfermedad.setVisible(true);
                   this.txtIdEnfermedad.setVisible(true);
                   this.lblNomenfermedad.setVisible(true);
                   this.txtNomEnf.setVisible(true);
                   this.txtDescripEnf.setEnabled(false);   
                   this.btnAgregar.setEnabled(true);
                   this.btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
                   this.btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);
                   this.btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
                   this.btnSalir.setEnabled(true);
              }
              else{
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay ID seleccionado para hacer la consulta");
              }
      }
      catch (Exception e){          
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se Conecto a la Base de Datos MySQL (Consulta por ID). Error:" + e.toString());
      }
 }
public class conexion {
Connection conectar = null;    
String usuario = "root";
String clave = "My@SQL@417@419";
String cadena="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nuestrasrarosariodb"; //?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

public Connection estableceConexion(){
   try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
       conectar= DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, usuario, clave);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se Conecto a la Base de Datos MySQL");
        return conectar;
   } 
   catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se Conecto a la Base de Datos MySQL. Error:" + e.toString());
        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Has presentado un código donde lanza una excepción con el mensaje "No se ejecutó el Procedmiento almacenado SP_VerenfermedadesX_ID" pero no es el mismo mensaje que aparece en tu segunda imagen. Deberías mostrar el código donde lanza la excepción con el mensaje de la segunda imagen.

Comment: Al final agregué el código que llama al darle click en el Jtable /Grid.

Comment: Bien. Una recomendación. Debes imprimir o loguear tus excepciones. En tu `catch` solo muestras un mensaje de error personalizado. Eso está bien. Deberías añadir un `System.out.println(e)` para saber en qué línea, clase y método provocó esa excepción. Si usas una API para loguear podrías usarla en lugar de System.out.println.

Comment: Hola, al poner el mensaje que me recomendaste, muestra lo siguiente :java.lang.NullPointerException. Lamentablemente, no me dice donde está el error.

Comment: Eso es un poco raro, porque si muestras la excepción mediante System.out.println(excepcion) debería mostrarte la pila de llamadas donde apareció la excepción. Puedes usar el método `printStackTrace()` de la excepción, que hará lo mismo (imprimir en pantalla la pila de llamadas donde apareció la excepción)

Comment: Esto es lo que me muestra:com.​mycompany.​sistema.​MySql.​conexion
public ResultSet ConsultaEnfermedadXID(int Id_enfermedad)
Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or there is no attached Javadoc to the JAR file containing this item:C:\Saulo\NetBeans\Sistema\sistema\target\classes
Attach Javadoc...

Comment: Cerrre tu pregunta porque el error dice que claramente pp es null.. no figura por ningun lado que es pp... asi que si las respuestas que estan en la duplicada no te sirven, por favor avisa porque...

Comment: Me muestra esto en la zona de consola, algo sobre un "javadoc":  public ResultSet ConsultaEnfermedadXID(int Id_enfermedad)
Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or there is no attached Javadoc to the JAR file containing this item:C:\Saulo\NetBeans\Sistema\sistema\target\classes
Attach Javadoc...

Comment: No entiendo, ya puse validación desde la interfaz, hasta en la clase. Mejor, dejo en paz a Java... Gracias.